# Run incoming requests in threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I wrote a python script that connects to an TCP socket (plaintext) and wait for requests. The TCP connection is persistent, alls requests and response are handle over the same one connection. See https://openvpn.net/community-resources/management-interface/ for technical docs.

My current script works fine, but it's single threaded. I'm using the python select api for wait until new data on the socket is available, then do something and write a response back. While do some stuff (it could be time.sleep(30) as example) the whole application is blocked a new request wont be answer.

Since the requests have identifier, the responses must not send in the same order as the requests send.

Minimalistic code example of the current solution:

```py
import select
import socket
import time


def _socket_recv(_sock) -> str:
    """Receive bytes from socket and convert to string.
    """
    buffer_size = 4096  # 4 KiB
    data = b""
    while True:
        part = _sock.recv(buffer_size)
        data += part
        if len(part) < buffer_size:
            # either 0 or end of data
            break

    return data.decode("utf-8")


def do_work(data: str) -> None:
    print(data)
    # Do something
    time.sleep(10)

    ret = "status 1\n"
    s.send(bytes(ret, "utf-8"))


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("{}".format('127.0.0.1'), 8081))

# Password
s.send(bytes("pass\n", "utf-8"))

while True:
    # wait until data is available
    _ = select.select([s], [], [])[0]

    # CLIENT notifications may be multi-line, and
    # the sequentiality of a given CLIENT notification, its associated environmental
    # variables, and the terminating ">CLIENT:ENV,END" line are guaranteed to be
    # atomic.
    notifications = _socket_recv(s)

    if notifications.startswith(">CLIENT:"):
        do_work(notifications)
```

Maybe a ThreadPool/WorkerPool should be a good approach, but how to manage concurrents writes to the TCP socket? Should the thread write to the socket? There are known frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce a buffer between socket and process engine, as below.

```py
import select
import socket
import time


def _socket_recv(_sock) -> str:
    """Receive bytes from socket and convert to string.
    """
    buffer_size = 4096  # 4 KiB
    data = b""
    while True:
        part = _sock.recv(buffer_size)
        data += part
        if len(part) < buffer_size:
            # either 0 or end of data
            break

    return data.decode("utf-8")

buffer=[]
def do_work() -> None:
    while True:
        if len(buffer)>0:
            data=buffer.pop(0)
            print(data)
            # Do something
            time.sleep(10)

            ret = "status 1\n"
            s.send(bytes(ret, "utf-8"))


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("{}".format('127.0.0.1'), 8081))

threading.Thread(target=do_work).start()

# Password
s.send(bytes("pass\n", "utf-8"))

while True:
    # wait until data is available
    _ = select.select([s], [], [])[0]

    # CLIENT notifications may be multi-line, and
    # the sequentiality of a given CLIENT notification, its associated environmental
    # variables, and the terminating ">CLIENT:ENV,END" line are guaranteed to be
    # atomic.
    notifications = _socket_recv(s)

    if notifications.startswith(">CLIENT:"):
        buffer.append(notifications)
```